# Get LinearLayout by Id returning null using Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-linearlayout, xamarin, nullreferenceexception

Why do I have `mainLayout==null`?

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
    LinearLayout mainLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Layout.Main);//return null
    mainLayout.Touch+=(s,e)=>
    {
         //something
    }
}
```

How can I get MainLayout  or how add event handler Touch?

**Resource.designer.cs**:

```
public partial class Layout
{
    public const int Main = 2130903041;
    //other
}
```

Comment: I hope this is some kind of pseudo code? - if so, post your real code.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Take a look at the tag: xamarin. More on it: [Xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/introduction_to_mobile_development)

Comment: @PhilippJahoda This is part of real code (C#, Xamarin)

Comment: Ow, sorry then, I missed that small little tag. I will edit your question and put it in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout> 
                                   (Resource.Layout.Main);//return null
```

You are using a layout file as the argument: `Resource.Layout.Main`

What you should be using is the `id` you assigned to your LinearLayout inside `Resource.Layout.Main`.

Try:

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout> 
                                   (Resource.Id.linear_layout_id);
```

Comment: `public const int Main = 2130903041;` isn't it ID?

Comment: @Olena No. The id has to be assigned to the LinearLayout in the xml file. This is how it will be found. Add `android:id="@+id/mylinearlayout"` to the LinearLayout and use `LinearLayout mainLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>            (Resource.Id.mylinearlayout);`

Answer (score 5):

Set a ID (android:id="@+id/mainLayoutID") on your XML that contains the LinearLayout called "mainLayout".

Then:

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Your layout reference
    final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayoutID);

}
```